# GDB: There is no member named ""

Tags: c++, debugging, makefile, g++

I'm writing some code that is calling some classes from a much larger project. Let's call the large project **SampleProject**. I have the static library of the SampleProject called libSampleProject.a. I cannot show the actual code, but I will provide some examples:

Let's say the SampleProject has a Class named SamplePointers in a source file called SamplePointers.cpp.

In the SamplePointers.cpp, there are pointers to other classes within the SampleProject.
So for example, there is a class named ReadXml, and ReadXml is a member of the SamplePointers class as a pointer.

```
class SamplePointers {
    public:
        ReadXml * readXmlObject;
        <MANY OTHER POINTERS TO CLASSES>
}
```

**FYI: the pointers are initialized in the constructor of the SamplePointers class.**

In my CPP file, main.cpp, where I'm calling said Class looks like this following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SampleClass.hpp>

int main() {
    SamplePointers * sampleObject = new SamplePointers;
    sampleObject->read("sampleFile.xml");
    std::cout << sampleObject->readXmlObject->xmlDataField << "\n";
}
```

SamplePointers also has a read function which reads in XML Fields. The fields will be available in the ReadXml class via accessing member variables. Running this executable, the value for **xmlDataField** prints out. However, when debugging on GDB, I set a breakpoint on say the read line, and then I type in this path, sampleObject->readXmlObject->xmlDataField, hit enter, and then gdb says that there is *no member named readXmlObject.*

This is curious, since I'm able to print it out, with std::cout, but gdb cannot physically access the object member variables.

Any ideas why gdb wouldn't be able to access the members?

Sample GDB output:

```
(gdb) file out
(gdb) b 7
(gdb) run
(gdb) <breaks at line 7>
(gdb) p sampleObject->readXmlObject->xmlDataField
There is no member named readXmlObject
```

Also, here is a look at what the Makefile looks like:

```
INCLUDES = -I/path/to/SamplePointersHeader -I/path/to/ReadXmlHeader -I/many/more/headers
main:
    g++ main.cpp $(INCLUDES) -L/path/to/SampleProjectLib -lSampleProject -o out
debug:
    g++ -g main.cpp $(INCLUDES) -L/path/to/SampleProjectLib -lSampleProject -o out
```

Comment: Does the library need to be compiled with debugging information? I don't use gcc much.

Comment: No, that was specifically added there so gdb can see the symbols. In this post I do not necessarily need it to compile properly. I edited the post to have two different Makefile targets.

Comment: You must compile with `-g` if you want to resolve symbols.  This makefile is not very useful (why not just have a shell script?) but when you debugged it did you run `make debug` first?  When you start GDB, does it print any messages about debugging the program like "No debugging symbols found"?

Comment: You've provided a lot of info here, but not the actually critical info: a cut and paste of the GDB command line you invoked and the output you got.

Comment: @MadScientist yes, of course I was compiling with -g, or else I would not have been able to see symbols. I added what the gdb session looks like.

Comment: If you compiled with optimizations enabled and the code is simple enough it's quite possible for the whole thing to be inlined.  Try compiling with `-O0` .

Comment: You are still eliding useful information such as info printed at GDB startup, what the actual line printed when GDB stops is, etc.  However, since we don't have it I will have to assume that none of that would help us figure it out.  If you run `p *sampleObject` what does it say?  Does the `readXmlObject` element appear there?  Does it have a simple pointer type?

Comment: @G.M. Good point. Now that I think about it, I think the library's object files may have been produced with -O3. Let me see if I can compile with -O0, re-make the library and try again. That may actually be why I cannot see anything.

Comment: @MadScientist yeah so the information that I provided is really the most I can do that would actually be helpful. I'm going to try what I said above and report back what I find. Also, `p *sampleObject` output the exact same message is before.

Comment: The answer has been posted below. Thanks for your guys' input, it was appreciated!

Comment: The output of `p *sampleObject` says _There is no member named readXmlObject_?  That's pretty strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @G.M., for the suggestion. I believe the problem may have been that when I made the library, I compiled it without the debug flag, i.e the `-g` flag. I re-compiled the library, made the library out of the object files, and even changed the optimization level from -O3 to -O0 which will help with debugging.

I then recompiled my `main.cpp` file with the newly made library, passed it through GDB and it was able to find the Class members.

Thanks for all of the input!